# App 'foo.main' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django

Прикручиваю миграции к вполне рабочему приложению, а оно — сабж.

Приложение в INSTALLED_APPS **есть**:

```
## projects/foo/foo/main/settings.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals

# ...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'foo.main',
]
```

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=foo.main.settings` прописан.

Я даже добавил принт в настройки:

```
(env) C:\Users\andreymal\projects\foo>python manage.py makemigrations foo.main
[u'django.contrib.admin', u'django.contrib.auth', u'django.contrib.contenttypes'
, u'django.contrib.sessions', u'django.contrib.messages', u'django.contrib.stati
cfiles', u'foo.main']
App 'foo.main' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?
```

(менять unicode на str пробовал — всё равно не работает)

Все нужные `__init__.py` также есть:

```
projects/
- foo/
  - foo/
    - main/
      - static/
      - __init__.py
      - models.py
      - settings.py
      - etc.
    - __init__.py
  - .gitignore
  - manage.py
  - setup.py
  - etc.
```

Вообще это всё прекрасно работает, сайт запускается, статика раздаётся (а для статики, на минуточку, тоже нужен прописанный INSTALLED_APPS — и он таки прописан).

Так что джанге ещё надо-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(как обычно, нахожу ответ сразу после создания опроса)

Внезапно выяснилось, что у джанги [есть странность](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/django-admin.html#app-names):

> Большая часть команд принимает список “названий приложений”. “Название приложения” – это название основного пакета приложения. Например, если настройка INSTALLED_APPS содержит строку 'mysite.blog', название приложения будет blog.

Таким образом, команда `python manage.py makemigrations main` прекрасно отрабатывает как надо.

Плюс к этому с выбором названий приложений стоит быть аккуратным, ибо если к `foo.main` добавить `bar.main`, то джанга заругается на совпадение:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: main